# cakePHP- retrieving from database. Models Associations & database

Tags: database, cakephp, cakephp-model

I feel pretty darn dumb for asking this question but I'm baffled, probably because I'm slightly intimidated with cakePHP(new to it, and not very comfortable),but its merits are practically forcing me to use it. So please if you could help, I appreciate it :

My problem is with understanding how  Model association works. After going through all the section about associations here I am still struggling and actually am not quite sure whether either my database design is flawed, or the associations between the models, are wrong.

Here it is : I have 3 Models, which are : 
Donor, BloodGroup, DonorType

To start with, I am not completely sure if I should create a model for every table in the db. 
My tables look like this :

```
+-------donors-------+
| donor_id  (pk)     |
| name               |
| surname            |
| donor_type_id (fk) |    
| blood_group_id (fk)|
|                    |
+--------------------+
+----donor_types-----+
| type_id (pk)       |
| type               |
|                    |
+--------------------+

+----blood_groups----+
| blood_group_id(pk) |
| group              |
|                    |
+--------------------+
```

Donor Model

```
class Donor extends AppModel{
    public $hasOne = array(
        'BloodGroup'=> array(
            'className' => 'BloodGroup'

        ),
        'DonorType' => array(
            'className' => 'DonorType'
        )
    );
```

According to the tables in the database, above is how the relationships can be described. I am already using the association to register a new donor with values retrieved from the blood group table/model, using this code in my controller:

> $this->set('bloodGroups', $this->Donor->BloodGroup->find('list',
>               array('fields' => array(
>                   'BloodGroup.blood_group_id','BloodGroup.blood_group'
>                   )
>               )
>           ));

Therefore I think the association is correct. However, now I want to display the stored users with the relevant details, but an sql error is being generated :

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'BloodGroup.donor_id' in 'on clause'
```

This is ofcourse because there is no 'donor_id' as a fk inside the BloodGroup table, by actually there is a blood_group_id as a fk inside the donor table. 
So what is the solution to this? Is the db design flawed or is there a way I can redefine the association within cake ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appear to be 2 things wrong with your setup.

1. You are not following Cake database conventions. Unless your hands are tied (e.g. external datasource you have no control over), your primary key should always be called `id`, not `table_name_id`. Cake always looks for `id` keys by default. If you have no choice, you can set a custom primary key by setting the [primaryKey](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#model-primarykey) property in your model.
2. By looking at your tables, you seem to be mixing up [hasOne](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasone) with [belongsTo](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#belongsto). Even though in plain English it sounds logical that a donor has one blood group, from a database standpoint, the donor belongs to a certain blood group. The manual has some notes that help you pick the right one:

> **hasOne:** the *other* model contains the foreign key.
>   **belongsTo:** the *current* model contains the foreign key.

This is also illustrated with some examples in the documentation (see links above). The latter one is true in your case, so your model should eventually look like this:

```
class Donor extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'BloodGroup',
        'DonorType'
    );

}
```

Comment: thanks for clarifying hasOne/ belongsTo.. About the primary key, what if I needed to have 
`echo $this->Form->input('blood_group_id')
echo $this->Form->input('type_id')`

Comment: You could perfectly do that from a form for `Donor`. Cake even helps you further if you follow conventions and set `$bloodGroups` and `$type` as arrays to your view and it will create dropdowns with all possible values from the related models.

Comment: First of, many thanks Oldskool! Secondly, Yes I am currently doing that! So how will I tell cakePHP that   
`$this->Form->input('id')` for the blood_group table   AND 
`$this->Form->input('id')` for the donor_type table

are not the same? Does it know internally somehow?

Comment: @user2678538 You shouldn't have two inputs with the same name, you should have `$this->Form->create('Donor'); $this->Form->input('Donor.blood_group_id'); $this->Form->input('Donor.donor_type_id');`, that should save all the data you need and when setting `$bloodGroups` and `$donorTypes` to your view from your Controller, it will automatically fill the dropdowns.

Comment: @Oldkool Thanks for the reply, I was simply doing  `echo $this->Form->input('blood_group_id')` and  `echo $this->Form->input('donor_type_id)` respectively, ie without explicitly specifying the model! I am guessing its good practice to do it as you described?