# cakePHP - data retrieval - Model Association & database design

Tags: database, cakephp, cakephp-model

I feel pretty darn dumb posting this question, but im completely baffled (probably because im quite new to cake and a bit intimidated)..

```
                      hasOne               hasOne

       donors         |      blood_groups     |       donor_types

Att ------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+           
    DonorID (pk)      |   blood_group_id (pk) |     type_id (pk)    |
    Name              |   group               |     type            |
    Surname           |                       |                     |
    type_id(fk)       |                       |                     |
    blood_group_id(fk)|                       |                     |
```

The Donor Model

```
class Donor extends AppModel{
    public $hasOne = array(
        'BloodGroup'=> array(
            'className' => 'BloodGroup'

        ),
        'DonorType' => array(
            'className' => 'DonorType'
        )
    );
```

I am already using the assoctiated models to populate a an FormHelper input in the donor registration view, all is good.

However when I try to retrieve a donor record this error occurs

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'BloodGroup.donor_id' in 'on clause'

This ofcours means that cakePHP is looking for the fk donor_id inside blood_groups table. However the relationship is the other way around and the fk is stored within donors table.

I do not know whether the db design is flawed or if the association needs to be redefined within cake. please help, as I am quite new to cakePHP and I a practically forced to use it because of its merits. 
I have read all the section about Association between models in the cake doc, but I am still struggling. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this database setup, which is correct working the assocs would be:

- Donor belongsTo BloodType
- Donor belongsTo DonorType
- BloodType hasMany Donor
- DonorType hasMany Donor

But your foreign keys are wrong: [Follow the CakePHP conventions!](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html)

Model fields are supposed to be lower cased and underscored, PKs are expected to be just id and FKs are the model name of the assoc, singular, underscored with suffix _id. The PKs in the donors table are right.

Why are you even changing your own convention? DonorId vs blood_group_id as PKs? However, if you want to cause a mess name them like you want but you'll have to declare them explicitly then everywhere. See [linking models](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html).

I recommend you to do [the blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html) before messing with the framework to get a real project done.

Comment: sorry about DonorID, that was a pasted earlier version, one which I changed before implementing. This question was posted twice yesterday, but it did not seem to have been posted and therefore I reposted it.  This was the original post : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321001/cakephp-retrieving-from-database-models-associations-database/21321330?noredirect=1#comment32139276_21321330

Comment: Anyway, I did get the blog tutorial and actually found it pretty straight forward, as well as I have the OO background needed to understand whats happening (or so I thought, at least). In both posts, you all gave a good answer, and now I've realised the conventions are a huge factor!  And also you re the only one that gave me the relationships needed i.e I was missing the hasMany rel. So Kudos for that!! Which is why I'm accepting yours as the answer
Should I leave  the post or delete duplicate ones ?

Answer (score 1):

Change your Donor model as shown below:

I have added foreignKey in BloodGroup and conditions in DonorType:

```
  class Donor extends AppModel{
        public $hasOne = array(
            'BloodGroup'=> array(
                'className' => 'BloodGroup',
                'foreignKey' => 'blood_group_id'

            ),
            'DonorType' => array(
                'className' => 'DonorType',
                'conditions' => array('Donor.type_id' => 'DonorType.type_id')
            )  
        );
```

Reason for above error: If foreignKey is not defined in association array then CakePHP assumes that tablename_id is foreignKey.

Comment: thanks  your answer is also correct, since you specified that the fk would need to be explicitly defined in the assoc if not following cake's conventions!